# Doing counts for a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a dataframe "samp" with a column (let's call it "rating") which takes on several values (let's say one of the following: "good", "medium", "bad".)

I would like to group-by on several other columns and count the frequency of "good", "medium" and "bad" and report those frequencies in new columns. (So maybe col1 is movie year, col2 is genre, and then there should be three more columns telling you how many of each type of rating there were for each year and genre.)

```
 ddply(samp,c("col1","col2"), summarize, 
       good=table(samp$rating)["good"],
       medium=table(samp$rating)["medium"],
       bad=table(samp$rating)["bad"])
```

The problem is (I think) that the functions I'm defining are not in terms of the groups ddply is outputting, they are just constant functions of samp. How can I define the functions here so that they're functions of the groups?

I tried using an anonymous function:

```
 ddply(samp,c("col1","col2"), summarize, 
       good=function(df)table(df$rating)["good"],
       medium=function(df)table(df$rating)["medium"],
       bad=function(df)table(df$rating)["bad"])
```

I can never get it working though. I think the error I've gotten the most from this is

```
 Error in output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] : 
 incompatible types (from closure to logical) in subassignment type fix
```

So lay it on me. What's the ridiculously simple solution that did not turn up while I blundered around trying 948506 combinations of ddply and table? Thank you.

Comment: do you just want the count? how about `length(samp$rating == 'good')`

Comment: @rawr This command will return the length of the logical vector and not count the `TRUE`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove all instances of `samp$` inside `ddply` and it will work:

```
ddply(samp,c("col1","col2"), summarize, 
  good=table(rating)["good"],
  medium=table(rating)["medium"],
  bad=table(rating)["bad"])
```

Comment: Argh, I could swear I'd tried it, but yeah, it is that simple. Thank you for clearing this up!

Answer (score 1):

Generic data:

```
samp <- data.frame(rating=c("bad","medium","good","bad","medium","good"),
                   col1=c(2007,2010,2007,2009,2010,2010),
                   col2=c("fiction","fiction","fiction","drama","drama","drama"))
```

Code (you shouldn't use `samp$` before columns' names):

```
ddply(samp,c("col1","col2"), summarize, 
      good=sum(rating == "good"),
      medium=sum(rating == "medium"),
      bad=sum(rating == "bad"))
```

Output:

```
  col1    col2 good medium bad
1 2007 fiction    1      0   1
2 2009   drama    0      0   1
3 2010   drama    1      1   0
4 2010 fiction    0      1   0
```

Comment: Sven gets the check for fixing my dumb table() usage, but I'd like to thank you for the new version. I like the output slightly better, and I'll probably apply this approach. Thank you very much!